# Is there a fiduciary responsibility for agents in India?

Tags: india, financial-advisor

I have come across many agents, bank employees (including so called financial advisors) who won't think twice before recommending a policy/fund/instrument for the sole purpose of higher commission.

Is there a fiduciary responsibility/rule we can invoke and get agents to follow in India?

Comment: There's no such rule anywhere. Buyer beware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a fiduciary responsibility/rule we can invoke and get agents to follow in India?

Unfortunately there isn't something that is codified currently.

Various regulators are pushing things by various methods. i.e. Restricting the fees that can be paid to Brokers / Commission / Sales agents for the set of financial instruments regulated by them. For example IRDA would have guidelines on Insurance, SEBI on Stocks / funds etc. IRDA has even gone to the extent of verifying that Agents don't mis-sell by showing high illustrative number. They have to show multiple illustrative numbers.

There is also a push to get financial advisor certified via certification programs [[CFP]](http://www.fpsbindia.org/scripts/CFPCertification.aspx).

All this still does not prevent sales agents from selling things in which they get higher commission. This is universally true, walk into a electronics / consumer goods shop and the agent would try and sell a brand / model that has highest commission for him than what is right for the customer. The best advise in this case is one needs to be well informed and make a prudent decision.